# Java EE opensource monitoring tools

Tags: jakarta-ee, monitoring

I use JMeter and JavaMelody tools to generate charts for transactions, threads and response times, but I want to get more precised information.

I'm looking for tools that give me information about:

- kind of existing threads (like blocked or waiting)
- JDBC connection times
- EJB - bean pool (number of loaded beans)

It would be great if that tool generate visual reports, like charts. I saw several existing topics, but many of tools aren't free.

Answer (score 1):

WHat you are looking for is afaik not possible in a real generic way, as this is not written down in the specs and thus the vendors are free to provide that information in whatever way they like.

RHQ is trying to expose that data for JBoss AS application servers, so if you are using JBoss, you should have a look at it: http://rhq-project.org/

Comment: Thanks for help, but I'm looking for more generic tool. I have to test under several J2EE containers like: Geronimo, Glassfish, WebSphere, JOnAS and JBoss also;)

Comment: RHQ is (in theory) able to support all those listed containers, as support is done via plugins. In reality the only ones supported right now are JBoss AS servers (AS 4-7)